# Kotlin Extend Java Class - Abstract Method Getter Not Implemented

Tags: java, kotlin

Consider you have the following class in java

```java
public abstract class Base {
    public abstract Integer getId();
}
```

You then want to start adding Kotlin to your project, so you create a child of this class in Kotlin

```kotlin
class Child(var id: Int? = null) : Base() {

}
```

How do you do this? When defining `Child` as above, you get the error `Class 'Child' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun getId(): Int! defined in Base`

If you define it in the body instead:

```kotlin
class Child() : Base() {
    var id: Int? = null
}
```

You get the exception `Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getId()Ljava/lang/Integer;):  public final fun <get-id>(): Int? defined in Child public abstract fun getId(): Int! defined in Child`

It seems like you are unable to use the property name `id` since it clashes with the abstract method name. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can make it work, though it's a bit tricky.

```
class Child() : Base() {
    @get:JvmName("_getId") // any other name will do
    var id: Int? = null

    override fun getId(): Int? = id
}
```

Comment: Interesting...any thought why this is required?  I guess you can also do `@JvmField` on `id` and then define the getter /setter by yourself.

Comment: Also, isn’t the generated getter’s signature the same as the one you manually define? Seems weird that it wouldn’t work out of the box

Comment: I think the point is that you can't override a function with a property. Even if the function to override is clearly a getter and properties are basically getters/setters. This is the same if you create `fun getId()` in Kotlin and then try to override it in a subtype with a `val name` - this is not allowed. But this is just my understanding.

Comment: @aarbor: No, the generated getter has a different name than the manually defined `getId`.